# Why does Django template prevent HTML autocomplete from functioning?

Tags: python, html, django, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode. When I enable Django Template, HTML autocomplete doesn't work. I want to code Python and HTML at the same time. How can I solve this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in VSCode's settings.json, add the following : `emmet.includeLanguages": {"django-html": "html"}`